# MacOS Mojave - remove PHP installation from

Tags: php, bash, macos, command-line-interface

I followed this tutorial https://php-osx.liip.ch/ and installed the php 7.3 version on MacOSX Mojave, running

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

But now I changed my mind and I want remove it and return to a clean status; what are the steps I should follow to remove every trace of it? Thank you!

Comment: Silly question: is it possible to move it, or I have to close it and post it there?

Comment: I guess I have to delete it; I think I don't have sufficient reputation to request a migration or I don't know how it works

Answer (score 1):

When you get a shell script (e.g., with curl), and pipe that script to bash, the script can do anything you can do (whoever ‘you’ is when you run your command; if root, it could destroy your entire system).

The *only* way to undo the effects of a script would be to read the entire script, find out exactly everything that it did, and reverse that action, if possible.

While it's commonplace to download and execute a script from a web site, it is a very dangerous thing to do. It bypasses the checks that MacOS has for package installation (the installer command).

I've taken a look at the current version of https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh and it, in turn, downloads https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/php-osx.liip.ch/packager/packager.tgz, which expands into /usr/local/packager. So the answer to your question *might* be just to delete all of /usr/local/packager.

However, the script subsequently run a Python script, as root, which could have done all sorts of additional installation, file manipulation, virus installation, etc. I'm not going to go through the entire Python script and its modules.